# How to write a decrypt file.txt, using GPG Suite on macOS

Tags: macos, command-line, gnupg

I want to decrypt a file with *GPG Suite*.

I have tried opening *Terminal.app* and executing:

```
gpg -d /PathToTheFile/File.txt.gpg | gpg -o /APath/File.txt.
```

This gave the output:

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP-data found.
gpg: processing message failed: Unknown system error.
```

Comment: Do you have access to the public and private key that was used to encrypt the file?

Comment: Yes. The keys are in my keychain.

Comment: Have you tried to encrypt a test file then decrypt that test file?  The problem might be connected to the file your testing.  This is the reason I am asking about a test file.

Comment: Yes I tried the encryption with a test file. I have just tried again. The same error.

Comment: Which is not helpful without your public key, so that won't work, perhaps it's the key itself?

Comment: I have the solution.  <br/> gpg -o Test.txt -d Test.txt.gpg

Answer (score 0):

You're actually calling GnuPG twize:

```
gpg -d /PathToTheFile/File.txt.gpg | gpg -o /APath/File.txt
```

- The first invocation `gpg -d /PathToTheFile/File.txt.gpg` decrypts the file and omits the decrypted copy to standard out.
- The second invocation `gpg -o /APath/File.txt` does not have a command as argument, only the output option. In this case, GnuPG tries to guess what to do based on the input. From `man gpg`:

  ```
  gpg  may  be  run with no commands. In this case it will perform a reasonable
  action depending on the type of file  it  is  given  as  input  (an  encrypted
  message  is decrypted, a signature is verified, a file containing keys is
  listed, etc.).
  ```

  This requires some kind of OpenPGP input -- which the decrypted document is not.

The second invocation of GnuPG is the one that fails. I think you try to decrypt a file and save its content to the file in the `-o` parameter, which can be done without the second invocation of GnuPG:

```
gpg -o /APath/File.txt -d /PathToTheFile/File.txt.gpg
```